# Strange behavior javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
console.log("url/page/value".match(/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g));
```

Why this code return an array: [/page, /value]? Why captured symbol '/'?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wq93T/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = "url/page/value";
var regex = /\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;
var match = regex.exec(path);
console.log(match[0]); // "/page"
console.log(match[1]); // "page"

match = regex.exec(path);
console.log(match[0]); // "/value"
console.log(match[1]); // "value"

match = regex.exec(path);
console.log(match); //null
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhrAj/)

The array returned by `exec` contains the entire match in index 0, and captures (values in parenthesis) at subsequent indices (first at 1, second at 2, etc).

As a single line:

```
console.log(/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g.exec("url/page/value")[1]); // "page"
```

As a function that returns an array of captures:

```
var path = "url/page/value";
var regex = /\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g;

console.log(capturedMatch(path, regex, 1));

function capturedMatch(str, rgx, index) {
    var m;
    var res = [];
    while((m = rgx.exec(str)) != null) {
        res.push(m[index]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhrAj/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Because

1. the `\/` in your regex means: match the literal character `/` (the forward slash has to be escaped by a backslash because it is also the `/pattern delimiter/`)
2. the `g` modifier makes you return all matches

Taken together, the regex `\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` means:

1. match the literal character `/`
2. match one or more characters that are letters or digits, capturing them to Group 1.

So this will match `/somethingLikeThis`

You can see that clearly in [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/hE0tC7), and experiment by adding strings to see what matches, or by editing the regex.

Comment: thank you! But how to get text after '/' but without this symbol?

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping `/` with `\` try this i.e.  `\/` means /

```
 console.log("url/page/value".match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g));
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression can be further simplified, if you do not want the `/`, to:

```
console.log("url/page/value".match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g));
```

Or

```
console.log("url/page/value".match(/[^\/]+/g));
```

Or

```
console.log("url/page/value".split('/'));
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wq93T/2/)